# Per-filetype "View whitespace" setting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to enable/disable the "View Whitespace" feature in Visual Studion on a per-filetype basis?  I'd like to be able to edit python files with visible whitespace, but not other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this.  The 'View White Space' setting (available from the Edit|Advanced|View White Space' menu option) is stored in the registry, which means the setting is applied to all files and all sessions of Visual Studio.

The next best thing is learn the shortcut key and toggle the feature on and off as necessary.  For Visual Studio 2008, the shortcut is Ctrl+E, S.

Comment: Yea, that's kinda what I figured.  Oh well.